# Word meaning: "by people/peers for people/peers"

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for a word that means something along the lines of "by people/peers for people/peers".

Comment: _Democracy_? Hard to say without context. There many not be any such word.

Comment: It might help if you gave more info about context. Do you mean in a political sense? People working together? Charity? Etc?

Comment: Basically like a peer1 -> peer2 type deal.  I provide content or video for sale and then a peer2 can buy that.  But peer2 can provide content or video as well for sale.  Basically like a big exchange.

Answer (score 1):

[cooperatively](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cooperatively)? especially if you take for example food [cooperatives](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cooperatively) where the food is produced and consumed by its members.